# How to integrate reCaptcha in Laravel Passport Api?

Tags: php, laravel, recaptcha, laravel-passport

I am trying to use google reCaptcha in my Laravel Passport api for login. I have a structure of code, but it's not working properly. I have a problem to call `AuthenticatesUsers` trait in my `validateRc` function (`validateRc` function is a part of another trait name `ReCaptcha`).

**ReCaptcha.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Validators;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers as AuthenticatesUsers;

trait ReCaptcha
{
    public function validateRc(Request $request){

        $recaptcha = $request->input('g-recaptcha-response');

        if($recaptcha){
            $client = new Client();

            $this->validate($request, [
                $this->
                $recaptcha => 'required|string'
            ]);
            $response = $client->post(
                'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
                ['form_params'=>
                    [
                        'secret'=>env('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET'),
                        'response'=>$recaptcha
                    ]
                ]
            );

            $body = json_decode((string)$response->getBody());

            if ($body->success)
            {
                Session::flash('Success','Human verified');   
                return redirect('/home');            
                $this->AuthenticatesUsers();
            } else {
                dd($body);
                Session::flash('Error','Robots not allowed');
                return redirect('/login'); 
            }

        } else {
            Session::flash('Error','Verification Incomplete');
        }
    }

}
```

**LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Validators\ReCaptcha as ReCaptcha;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */
    use ReCaptcha;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */


    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```